# Removing comma coming after a list-item word

Tags: string, list, python-2.7

This is my Python code (I am using Python 2.7.6):

```
cn = ['here,', 'there']
>>> for c in cn:
    if c.endswith(','):
        c = c[:-1]

>>> print(cn)
['here,', 'there']
```

As you can see, `cn[0]` still has the trailing comma even though I did `c = c[:-1]`. How do I change `cn[0]` so that it equals `'here'` without the trailing comma?

Comment: @juanchopanza Can't agree with you on that one; the problem here is not how to strip the comma, rather, how to change the list element.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yes, I tend to agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you assign a new value to `c` but do not update the list.
In order to manipulate the list in place you would need to do something like this:

```
cn = ['here,', 'there']
for index, c in enumerate(cn):
    if c.endswith(','):
        cn[index] = c[:-1]

print(cn)
['here', 'there']
```

Enumerate gives you all elements in the list, along with their index, and then, if the string has a trailing comma you just update the list element and the right index.

The problem with your code was that `c` was simply holding the string `'here,'`. Then you created a new string whithou the comma and assigned it to `c`, this did not affect the list `cn`. In order to have any effect on the list you need to set the new value at the desired position.

You could also use list comprehension to achive the same result which might be more pythonic for such a small task: (as mentioned by @AdamSmith)

```
cn = [c[:-1] if c.endswith(',') else c for c in cn]
```

This does creates a new list from `cn` where each element is returned unchanged if it does not end with `,` and otherwise the comma is cut off before returning the string.

Another thing you could use would be the built-in `rstrip` function, but it would remove all trialing commas, not just one. It would look something like this (again @AdamSmith pointed this out):

```
cn = map(lambda x: x.rstrip(','), cn)
```

Comment: maybe it would be valuable to tell **why**? describe here the difference between mutable object (list) and immutable (string)?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That doesn't apply here. The problem is if you mutate **the list** as you are iterating over it, because it changes the length and thus the results of the iteration. There's no problem at all with mutating the values you're iterating over. That's what you're doing 95% of the time you're iterating. Some of the answers on those linked questions do exactly what this one does.

Comment: It's certainly LESS pythonic to use a `list(map(...))`, but I'd rather see `cn = [c[:-1] if c.endswith(',') else c for c in cn]` list comp than the for loop you have above.

Comment: And assuming they're just trying to strip trailing commas, `map(lambda c: c.rstrip(','), cn)` does the job just fine!

Comment: @AdamSmith yeah, you're right. I'm gonna edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: `rstrip` would remove all the commas on the end of the string. OP wants to remove a single comma (at least, that's all that can be inferred from the example code). @AdamSmith

Comment: @ZachGates yes yes, I saw the argument in the other question. It's silly semantics that are handwaved away with my "assuming they're just trying to strip trailing commas." If you're not willing to assume that, then the whole suggestion is moot. No sense nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

What you did was copy the string with an edit, and store it in a new variable named `c`, with a name that clashed with the original `c` and overrode it.

Since you didn't change the original, it stays unchanged when the new one goes out of scope and gets cleared up.

You could do something like this to make a new list, containing the changed strings:

```
newlist = [c.strip(',') for c in cn]
```

Or, more closely to your example while keeping this approach:

```
cn = [c[:-1] if c.endswith(',') else c for c in cn]
```

The alternate loop-with-enumerate approach in another answer will work, but I'm avoiding it because in general, changing lists while iterating over them can lead to mistakes unless done carefully, and that makes me think it's a bad habit to get into in cases where there's another reasonably neat approach.

Comment: copying list (data) is not the same as mutating one element

Comment: This will strip *all* commas. The OP only strips 1.

Comment: @ZachGates Also commas at the beginning of the string.

Comment: You need `rstrip`, for example `cn = [c.rstrip(',') for c in cn]`

Comment: I meant for the beginning to be encompassed in "all". :P But yes, you're right; this is something the OP doesn't want. @jpmc26

Comment: That is still not what OP is asking for. They want to strip a single comma from the end, not all of them. @juanchopanza

Comment: Six comments claim this answer is wrong and it has a single downvote.

Comment: Six comments claim an answer is wrong, even though it fits the single example given in the question, a question which doesn't mention any specific requirements about leading commas or multiple commas. Certain commenters might be displaying psychic powers.

Comment: @ZachGates What do you mean by "all of them"? My example does what OP wants (except that it creates a new list)

Comment: You can infer, simply from the given code, that the OP wants to strip a single comma from the end of a string. `c[:-1]` removes a single character. @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: It will strip `foo,,,,,` to `foo`. The OP wants to strip `foo,,,,,` to `foo,,,,` (as far as we can tell from the sample code). @juanchopanza

Comment: @ZachGates Oh, I see, you mean it removes consecutive commas at the end. I would bet my house that OP actually wants that. If I had a house.

Comment: @ZachGates, I wouldn't bet my house on it, but I'd guess that OP never considered that there might be an entry with multiple commas, or commas at the start, and threw together an example off the top of their head. I could be wrong.

Comment: I agree. I've switched my down to an up after your edit. Nice work fixing it. @TessellatingHeckler

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I'm don't think we were saying it was wrong. Rather, we were saying that it may exhibit behavior that could be desirable or undesirable to the OP. The question is not entirely clear on whether they wish to strip multiple or leading commas or not, so I didn't feel a downvote was warranted.

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the loop variable `c`, but you aren't changing the list `cn`. To change the list `cn`, instead of looping through its *values*, loop through its *indexes*. Here's an implementation.

```
for c in range(len(cn)):
    if cn[c].endswith(','):
        cn[c] = cn[c][:-1]
```

Comment: it's odd to see this type of structure in Python. You should much prefer `for idx, value in enumerate(cn)`.

Comment: @AdamSmith Wow, I never thought that way! Another Python technique to add to my brain...